# Copy one nested go struct to another

Tags: go, struct

I am trying to copy one nested go struct to another which has same fields at the very end.

I have these structs

```
type Server struct {
    Name string
    ACL []ACLRule
}
type ACLRule struct {
    Id   int
    Role string
}

type Client struct{
    Name string
    ACL []*ClientACLRule
}

type ClientACLRule struct {
    Id   int
    Role string
}
```

I have initialized the client struct like this

```
client := &Client{
        Name: "Test",
        ACL:  []*ClientACLRule{
            {
                Id:   1,
                Role: "client1",
            },
            {
                Id:   2,
                Role: "client2",
            },
        },
    }
```

With all the necessary data.

and i have this server struct

```
server := &Server{
        Name: "",
        ACL:  []ACLRule{},
    }
```

now i want have an automated way of copying the client struct's data to the server struct.

the structs have the same structure but only the nested structs are of diff types.

If they had simple types then i can just use conversion and copy the struct like below

```
foo := Foo{Id: "123", Name: "Joe"}
bar := Bar(foo)
```

but for nested struct, i need some help how to copy.

Comment: There is no trick to do here: You need to do some programming and copy over all relevant parts.

Comment: You can add json tags to your struct fields. Then marshal your source data of one struct to bytes then unmarshal the bytes into another struct. This method works as long as your different structs have same json naming and type